# Access variable from UITableViewCell in the TableViewController for specific cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to coding iOS. I have a TableViewCell which has a boolean in it (to check if my like button has been pressed).

```
class ChinTwoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var bodyText: UITextView!

var likeCheck:Bool = false

// Other code

@IBAction func likeTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if((likeCheck) == false) {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        likeCheck = true
    } else {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        likeCheck = false
    }
}
```

}

I would like to access this boolean in my TableViewController, and then check if true, do stuff, if false, do stuff.

How can I check this so that it pertains to the correct row in the other class?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the bool directly in the UITableViewCell I suggest you create a model class.

The view controller would keep an array of model classes with it. In cellForRow callback the controller can pass the model class to the cell and the cell can modify it if required.

Comment: As I am new to coding iOS, what what a model class entail and how do I link up the timeline from the tableViewController to this new class? I am using parse by the way, if that makes a difference. And also, would you suggest deleting this boolean completely? How should I track if it has been clicked then?

Comment: The model class can contain only the Boolean that is in the UITableViewCell as of now. So you would move the bool from table view cell to the model class. In the .h file of the table view cell declare a property of type of the new model class. view controller would create model classes for all rows of the table view and initially set the bool for all model classes to NO. You can pass the model class from the view controller to table view cell in the cellForRow callback of UITableViewDataSource protocol.